Is the ILIKE Operator in QGIS not working correctly?
Seems the ILIKE operator is not working in the QGIS-Query-Builder:

Using LIKE works correctly:

Can anybody confirm this bad behaviour?

Which version of QGIS (v3.xx?)

if your data format relies on gdal (with QGIS) there is an open ticket https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/8835

But the issue in the ticket seems to be about opposite case, ILIKE finds rows but LIKE does not. What is the format of the OSM data?

The title it the input box of the query builder gives a hint:
Provider Specific Filter Expression

I guess that your layer comes from GeoPackage. GeoPackage is an SQLite database, and because SQLite does not have ILIKE the provider gives an error. A simple test confirms this: convert the GeoPackage layer into GeoJSON, add the layer into QGIS, and then ILIKE will work. That happens because GeoJSON is opened with a GDAL provider, and the GDAL OGRSQL dialect does support ILIKE https://gdal.org/en/latest/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html
I do not know if this is good news for you, but in SQLite you do not need ILIKE because LIKE is case insensitive. See for example https://sqlite.org/forum/info/af7978156ce072e7e1060f0741dc10d33dc7ccaf702f6d67c5ab692bffa25174
It would be nice if QGIS could show more explicit error, or if the ILIKE button would be de-activated for GeoPackage, SpatiaLite and other SQLite based layers, but maybe that is too complicated.
The documentation of the GDAL SQLite SQL dialect https://gdal.org/en/latest/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#like-operator claims that GDAL understands also ILIKE since version 3.9, but I made a test with GDAL 3.10.0dev and that does not seem to be true.
EDIT
The misleading part of the GDAL documentation is corrected via https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/9b1ab02e7b8cb5504cb65cacb287bc717ccee3f7 and the link above does not show ILIKE any more. Check the commit if you are interested in seeing the old wrong wording.

At 3.34.10, I note the following when using ILIKE with GPKG: Filtering fails when r-clicking the layer in the Layers panel > Filter.  However, ILIKE works correctly from the Attribute table, either when 1) using the Advanced Filter (Expression), or 2) when using the Select Features Using an Expression button.

SQLite certainly lack ILIKE and you can confirm that by opening a GeoPackage database with some regular SQLite software like DB Browser for SQLite.  Using ILIKE returns an error "Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "ILIKE": syntax error". QGIS is probably using its own code when Expressions are used instead of passing the SQL to the backend.

FWIW, I’ve voted to reopen this post, because I think it uncovers some important details about QGIS functionality.
